# Fire INotifyPropertyChanged on object reassignment

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have 2 windows, mainWindow & editWindow. editWindow has a save button. Both windows bind to properties on instances of a Robot class.

editWindow uses a deep clone copy (makes a new instance) of the Robot instance mainWindow uses.  When the user hits the editWindow save button I want to reassign properties of the cloned instance back to the original instance on mainWindow.

If mainWindow is bound to robot1 & editWindow is bound to robot2, I know `robot1 = robot2` will break bindings and not fire INotifyPropertyChanged on the original instance.

How can I reassign the properties of robot2 to robot1 so robot1 is still the bound item? The simple route is to copy each property one at a time, but I'll be doing this on several forms with different types of objects. I'd like to do this generically.

Comment: Change `robot1` and `robot2` to be properties and move the logic to the setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. The first is simply to copy the value of each property from one object to the other. The second is to use reflection to find all public properties of the object and to copy them to the other. The first option is much quicker to implement and would typically be done in the data class, eg. add a `CopyValuesTo` method that would look something like this:

```
public void CopyValuesTo(YourDataType dataType)
{
    Property1 = dataType.Property1;
    Property2 = dataType.Property2;
    ...
    PropertyN = dataType.PropertyN;
}
```

Comment: I can do that, but I have to imagine using bound properties on a window & not wanting to update them until a user clicks save is a fairly common problem.  Is this the standard, or am I just implementing it wrong?

Comment: This is fairly typical, unless you want to get into reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Property of `robot1` named `Robot1`.

Firstly create a class:

```
public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged {

[field: NonSerialized]
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged( string propertyName ) {
    if ( PropertyChanged != null ) {
        PropertyChanged(
            this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

Then make your `Robot` class intherit from `Notifier` like this:

```
public class Robot :Notifier{...}
```

After that, you make an attribute in your `ViewModel`:

```
private Robot robot1;
```

Initialize in your constructor maybe.
And create a property:

```
public Robot Robot1 {
        get {
            return robot1;
        }
        set {
            robot1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Robot1");
        }
    }
```

If you bind your UI to `Robot1`, and then update it like

```
Robot1 = robot2;
```

It will not break the binding, and update the UI element.